# Docker Compose throws invalid type error

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm having an issue running docker compose. Specifically i'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.login-service.environment contains {"REDIS_HOST": "redis-server"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string
```

And here's my yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - my-network

  login-service:
    tty: true
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - my-network
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST: redis
    command: bash -c "./wait-for-it.sh redis:6379 -- npm install && npm run dev"

networks:
  my-network:
```

Clearly the issue is where I set my environment variable even though i've seen multiple tutorials that use the same syntax. The purpose of it is to set `REDIS_HOST` to whatever ip address docker assigns to Redis when building the image. Any insights what I may need to change to get this working?

Comment: Take out the leading `- `  to fix the syntax error. That is, `environment` either expects a list of  `key=value`, or is a dict of `key: value`.

Comment: you dont need to use `environment` here at all, if you are inside login-service container and you will do `ping redis` it will redirect to current IP of the redis, how is the `REDIS_HOST` variable handled inside the login-service container?

Answer (score 30):

There are two different ways of implementing it. One with `=` sign and other with `:` sign. Check the following examples for more information.

Docker compose environments with `=` sign.

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    environment:
      - USER=john
      - EMAIL=johh@gmail.com
```

Docker compose environments with `:` sign

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    environment:
      USER:john
      EMAIL:johh@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 9):

It happens because the leading dash. You can try without it like below:

```
environment:
  REDIS_HOST: redis
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I had two environment variables for a service in my docker-compose.yml file, I was getting the error `services.web.environment.1 must be a string` because one of the environment variables was

`- REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD}`

This syntax means that the `REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD` variable is not set probably because for docker compose version 3.9 setting an enviornment variable with this syntax is not allowed and does not work.

When using `REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD}`, your IDE's syntax highlighting will show `REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD` in blue and `${REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD}` in red. This means that `REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD}` is not a string, and when setting an environment variable it must be a string. The way to solve this problem is to set the environment variable in your docker-compose.yml file using the syntax:

`REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD=${REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD}`

Now your IDE should show `REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD=${REDIS_DATABASE_PASSWORD}` in red, meaning it is a string.